# I am specifying the fixed width of the child div of the container, how to prevent flexbox from changing this width when an overflow occurs?

Tags: css

I am using `flexbox`. Each child `div` has a `width:200px`, my idea is that a horizontal `scroll` occurs when it exceeds more than 100% of the container.
For some reason, flexbox makes the elements as small as it can to avoid this `overflow`. How can I fix it?
I need `overflow` horizontal, and each `div` with `width:200px` and the margin setted

```css
.flex{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  background:yellow;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
}

.flex div{
 width:200px;
 background:red;
 margin:0px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
/*  width:100%; */
  background: yellow;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex div {
  width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: red;
  margin: 0px 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
  <div> hello </div>
</div>
```

Did you want something like this??

Comment: awesome, can you please explainme why `flex: 0 0 auto`?

Comment: You could read about it here https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/